# Find element not found in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have component in AngularJS and a template which looks something like the following

**Template**

```
<div id="{{ $ctrl.idName }}"></div>
```

And the component controller looks something like this

**Component controller**

```
export class SomeCtrl {

    idName: string = "idName";

    constructor(public $element) {

    }

    $postLink(): void {
        const divElement = this.$element.find(`#${ this.idName }`);
        console.log(divElement); //divElement is undefined
    }
}
```

For some reason `divElement` becomes undefined, however if I write the name in the template as following

```
<div id="idName"></div>
```

Then the element is found. My assumption that it was due to template hasn't finished compiling. But it seems not because of that either since the `$postLink()` method is fired when compiling is finished according to the following article [ThoughtRam - Exploring Angular 1.5: Lifecycle Hooks](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: angular.element `find()` only works with tagName selectors if you aren't including jQuery. If you *are* including jQuery would need the `#` prefix

Comment: Hi @charlietfl , sorry I missed the # prefix in my example. It was included and yes jQuery is included as well. I corrected my example now.

Comment: @charlietfl yes jquery.js is loaded before angular.js

Comment: `minus voters` are free to write down what they think is unclear with my question

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the `find` in a `$timeout`:

```
export class SomeCtrl {

    idName: string = "idName";

    constructor(public $element, public $timeout) {

    }

    $postLink(): void {
        this.$timeout( _ => {
            const divElement = this.$element.find(`#${ this.idName }`);
            console.log(divElement); 
        });
    }
}
```

This will allow the AngularJS framework and the browser time to render the interpolation.

Comment: That did resolve my issue. But kind of hackish solution isn't it?